# postback and validation in asp.net and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, postback

I have this much

**HTML**

`<asp:Button ID="btnSaveContest" runat="server" Text="Save &amp; Publish Contest" OnClientClick=" ValidateCreateContest();"
                            ValidationGroup="ContestAdd" OnClick="btnSaveContest_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>`

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateCreateContest() {
        Page_ClientValidate();
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            alert('page is valid');
            $('#<%=btnSaveContest.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            __doPostBack('<%=btnSaveContest.ClientID%>', '')
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('not valid');      
            return false;
        }     

    }
</script>
```

It does post back to the page, but it does not go to the server side function **btnSaveContest_Click**. Why ?

Comment: I have had some troubles doing similar things to this. One solution I found was to do `OnClientClick="ValidateCreateContest(); return isFormValid;"`, and then in the `ValidateCreateContest();` function do `isFormValid = true`, `isFormValid = false` as required, with `isFormValid` being a global variable.

Comment: @Oliver :- It did postback, but it did not go to the btnSaveContest_Click function... ???

Comment: first check if there is any javascript error in the page using error console. 
if you are checking it using a breakpoint then stop the project make a clean build and then again rebuild and run the project see if it helps and if this does not work try changing the default browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `ClientID`, use `UniqueID`

```
    if (Page_IsValid) {
        alert('page is valid');
        $('#<%=btnSaveContest.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        __doPostBack('<%= btnSaveContest.UniqueID %>', '')
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('not valid');      
        return false;
    }
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612016/c-asp-net-why-is-there-a-difference-between-clientid-and-uniqueid) may be useful.

Comment: @_onof      would you please tell the difference between ClientId And UniqueId.please explore your answer a bit it will help OP.Thanks

Comment: @Devjosh  - http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t78409-difference-between-id-clientid-and-uniqueid.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612016/c-asp-net-why-is-there-a-difference-between-clientid-and-uniqueid

Comment: @mraufk & onof:Thanks for your explanation and help links it will surely help me