# RequiredFieldValidator not working in a repeater

Tags: c#, validation, repeater

I'm trying to dynamically add a RequiredFieldValidator to a RadioButtonList in a repeater, but it fails with the error:

```
Unable to find control id 'rblAccessory_40' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of ''.
```

The code for this section is:

```
            if ((e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header) && (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer))
        {

            Label lblAccID = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblAccID");
            RadioButtonList rblCondition = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rblCondition");

            rblCondition.ID = "rblAccessory_" + lblAccID.Text;


            if (conditionList.Count() > 0)
            {
                RequiredFieldValidator rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator();
                rfv.ControlToValidate = "rblAccessory_" + lblAccID.Text;
                rfv.ErrorMessage = "Please complete the accessories section";
                pnlValidation.Controls.Add(rfv);

                rblCondition.DataSource = conditionList;
                rblCondition.DataValueField = "id";
                rblCondition.DataBind();
            }
            foreach (ListItem li in rblCondition.Items)
            {
                li.Text = "";
                li.Value = "AccessoryID_" + lblAccID.Text + "-ConditionID_" + li.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is definitely finding the RadioButtonList (rblCondition) because the data is binding correctly at this point:

```
                rblCondition.DataSource = conditionList;
                rblCondition.DataValueField = "id";
                rblCondition.DataBind();
```

So I don't understand why the error says it is unable to find the control ID.

I've tried specifying the control ID manually, as below:

```
rfv.ControlToValidate = "rblAccessory_" + lblAccID.Text;
```

and have also tried:

```
rfv.ControlToValidate = rblCondition.ID;
```

lblAccID is a hidden text field used to store the ID of the row in the repeater.

Comment: Updated my answer.  I ran into a very similar problem recently and below is how I solved it.  I'm assuming you're creating your controls in the `ItemCreated` event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assign the control to validate property AFTER the `ItemCreated` event.  I know this sounds weird, how would you still have the reference to the dynamically created control?  I've gotten around this by keeping a reference to a `List<Action>` reference which I add things to during `ItemCreated` to be executed later.

In your control class you'll declare your `List<Action>` object:

`List<Action> deferringControlToValidateUntilPreRender = new List<Action>();`

Inside the `ItemCreated` event you'll have a line that looks like:

`deferringControlToValidateUntilPreRender.Add(() => rfv.ControlToValidate = rblCondition.UniqueID);`

And then, later, perhaps in `PreRender`:

`foreach(var deferredAction in deferringControlToValidateUntilPreRender) action();`

Comment: Generally I would suggest using UniqueID instead of ClientID.  There's less things that can go wrong when using UniqueID, at least that's what my experience has been so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `RequiredFieldValidator` is client-side code, you need to use the client id of the control. Like this:

```
rfv.ControlToValidate = rblCondition.ClientID;
```

Some more information from MSDN if you are interested:

[Control.ClientIDMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Also, an SO discussion on the differences between ClientID and UniqueID (as referenced in @MushinNoShin's answer, which, IMHO, is incorrect):

[Why is there a difference between ClientID and UniqueID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612016/c-sharp-asp-net-why-is-there-a-difference-between-clientid-and-uniqueid)